# Sort array using merge sort

Tags: c++, sorting, merge, conditional-statements, output

I am using merge sort for descending my array. What is the reason that my first element changed his value?
My half code works. But with my first and last elements something went wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

void Merge(int a[], int low, int high, int mid)
{
    int i = low, j = mid + 1, k = 0;
    int temp[high - low + 1];

    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if (a[i] > a[j])
            temp[k++] = a[i++];

        else
            temp[k++] = a[j++];
    }

    while (i <= mid) {
        temp[k++] = a[i++];
    }

    while (j <= high) {
        temp[k++] = a[j++];
    }
    for (i = low; i <= high; i++) {
        a[i] = temp[i - low];
    }
    return;
}

void MergeSort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if (low < high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        MergeSort(a, low, mid);
        MergeSort(a, mid + 1, high);

        Merge(a, low, high, mid);
    }

    return;
}

void output(int* a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << a[i] << "\t";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    MergeSort(a, 0, n);
    output(a, n);
}
```

The output must be this.

input 10

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

output

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

But I'm getting this
output

```
4197055 10  9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2
```

I'm a beginner in a c++. So I will be happy if you can help me to do my first steps here.

Comment: this code seems working, not able to reproduce. https://godbolt.org/z/nPqhn3

Comment: @foragerDev no it is not working https://godbolt.org/z/G9GPnv classic example of Undefined Behavior. (godblot with gcc is able to show line numbers: https://godbolt.org/z/1M7vrj)

Comment: @MarekR on my machine, I am not getting that.

Comment: @foragerDev again this is undefined behavior so it may crash it may do nothing it may print tash. Note the only difference is that I've enabled address sanitizer.

Comment: yes I am getting on the 2nd link.

Comment: You are passing `n` as `high`. But `n` is *one higher* than the index of the highest element, which causes undefined behavior. `MergeSort(a,0,n-1);` will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed up how ranges of indexes are described. In same cases you have made those ranges closed at the end and in other opened at the end. Result is undefined behavior buffer overrun.

Here is fixed version where `low` points to first element and `high` point one step beyond last element.

Remember that in C++ indexes of array `arr[n]` should be from `0` to `n - 1` inclusive.

```cpp
void Merge(int a[], int low, int high, int mid)
{
    int i = low, j = mid, k = 0;
    int temp[high - low];

    while (i < mid && j < high) {
        temp[k++] = a[i] < a[j] ? a[i++] : a[j++];
    }

    while (i < mid) {
        temp[k++] = a[i++];
    }

    while (j < high) {
        temp[k++] = a[j++];
    }

    for (i = low; i < high; i++) {
        a[i] = temp[i - low];
    }
    return;
}

void MergeSort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if (low + 1 < high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        MergeSort(a, low, mid);
        MergeSort(a, mid, high);

        Merge(a, low, high, mid);
    }

    return;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nET5YT

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
    {
        int n1 = m - l + 1;
        int n2 = r - m;
     
        int L[n1], R[n2];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
            L[i] = arr[l + i];
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++)
            R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];
    
        int i = 0;
     
        int j = 0;
    
        int k = l;
     
        while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
            if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
                arr[k] = L[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {
                arr[k] = R[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
     
        while (i < n1) {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
    
        while (j < n2) {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
     
    void mergeSort(int arr[],int l,int r){
        if(l>=r){
            return;
        }
        int m = (l+r-1)/2;
        mergeSort(arr,l,m);
        mergeSort(arr,m+1,r);
        merge(arr,l,m,r);
    }
    
    void output(int A[], int size)
    {
        for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 };
        int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
     
        mergeSort(arr, 0, arr_size - 1);
     
        output(arr, arr_size);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Try to use comments to guide users through your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Change this line: `Merge(a, low, high-1, mid);` as you are using **zero-based indexing**.

**Update:** previous change does not work for all cases.

Try this change only:`MergeSort(a, 0, n-1)`

**Try to use 1-based indexing for avoiding this type of case**

Comment: You didn't test that, did you?

Comment: @Beta it fixes UB https://godbolt.org/z/K5WTjv but result is invalid.